# How to apply bold text style for a range of text inside a cell using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How to make a range of text bold text style using Apache POI? 
Eg:

[image]

Instead of applying style for the entire cell.
I used to do this in vb.net with these lines of code:

```
excellSheet.Range("C2").Value = "Priority: " + priority
excellSheet.Range("C2").Characters(0, 8).Font.Bold = True
```

But I can't find the way to do that in Java using Apache POI.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [create your `Font` with bold styling, using the `Workbook` object](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#WorkingWithFonts).

```
Font font = workbook.createFont();
font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
```

Next, grab the `RichTextString` from the `Cell` and call the [`applyFont` overload that takes a range of indexes and the `Font` to apply](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html#applyFont(int,%20int,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font)).

```
RichTextString rts = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
rts.applyFont(0, 8, font);
```

You should reuse the `Font` object if you want to convert other text in the workbook to bold.