# Converting html tag styled text to styled text in XLS file with Primefaces DataExporter

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a p:textEditor in a JSF xhtml file:

```
                        <p:textEditor id="specQuestions" value="#{row[column.property]}"   >
                            <f:facet name="toolbar">
                                <span class="ql-formats">
                                    <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                                    <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                                    <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                                </span>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:textEditor>
```

As expected, text input into this field gets stored with html tags - `<p>, <em>, <u>` etc.

In another xhtml file in the same application I have a p:dataTable the cells of which display the content from the same p:textEditor instances.

```
<p:dataTable id="xlsTable" var="row" rendered="false"
                             rowIndexVar="rowVar" value="#{csvExportController.csvRows}" 
                             widgetVar="reportsTable"
                             >
                    <p:columns value="#{csvExportController.csvColumns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex"  >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{row[column.property]}" escape="false"   />
                    </p:columns>
                </p:dataTable>
```

The dataTable is not rendered (rendered="false"). Instead its purpose is to be exported to an xls file by means of a p:dataExporter like so:

```
<p:dataExporter type="xls" target="xlsTable" fileName="#{reviewTableController.spreadsheetTitle}" pageOnly="false" encoding="utf-8" />
```

As might be anticipated, but is not wanted, when the data is exported to xls, all the html tags render literally as tags (`<em>` etc) in the xls cells. What I want is for the text in `<em>` tags to be rendered Italic in the xls file, `<u>` as underlined text, etc.

I'm guessing I should be customizing the dataExporter (?)
With a customized dataExporter it seems like you can style cells. But what makes this case harder is that the text within a given cell might be variously styled. Its not as if all text within a given cell is a single style.

It looks like Apache poi has
- org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell, and
- org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
-- Nothing more granular than the level of an xls cell (?)

Is there any way of turning text with some simple html style tags into styled text (not styled cells as such, but styled text) in an xls file, whether as a prior process or in-process with p:dataExporter?

JSF 2.2, Primefaces 6.1.4, Java EE 7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851788/how-to-apply-bold-text-style-for-a-range-of-text-inside-a-cell-using-apache-poi

Comment: vsevolod - thank you - the second link in particular looks promising.